Official source for Windows 10 checksums?
We can find ISO files of installation media of Windows 10 in many sources.
Is there a source, e.g. some part of the Microsoft website, for the checksums (SHA256 or another hash) of the installation media?
If I'm paranoid, even if I buy an installation media from a reseller, I don't know 100% if it's the real ISO. The only way to have a fully trusted installation media is to:

compute the SHA256 of the installation media I have
compare it with a SHA256 published on a trusted website, such as microsoft.com

Thus, all third party websites (such as those mentioned in Microsoft Windows ISO checksums, question for WinXP, 7, 8) which publish checksums are not 100% guaranteed.
Is that an official Microsoft source or trusted source for checksums of Windows installation media?
(valid for Windows 10 Pro ISO but also Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2021, such as "en-us_windows_10_enterprise_ltsc_2021_x64_dvd_d289cf96.iso")

The issue is more complex. Take a look at : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237474/whats-the-point-of-providing-file-checksums-for-verifying-downloads

@1NN Yes, it is a not-simple question, but quite useful.

Access this link:
Download windows-10-enterprise
Scroll down to Prerequisites
You will see the Verify Dowload section that have the download link of Windows10EnterpriseHashValues.pdf
For this link above Download Windows 10 Disc Image
You need to access it using mobile browser to be able to see the Verify your download section
Updated:
You can create an account on My Visual Studio
Access this link and search for Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2021
You will see the product and hash value of it on info tab 

Thanks @HiếuVũ, good to find a source for download links + SHA256 both on the official Microsoft website. This is for an EVAL version of Win10EnterpriseLTSC2021. Do you know if this EVAL ISO can be used permanently like a normal version if we enter a valid license key at the end? Or it always stays an evaluation version that can't be used longer than x weeks?

I have updated the answer. Please check it out!
The evaluation edition is to test with. You can not activate it to continue to use it forever. You also can't upgrade it to the full version, you need to reinstall windows.
If you want to use LTSC, illegal or not, you can NOT use the evaluation iso.

This is the solution, thanks @HiếuVũ! I'll give the bounty when available (in 7 hours).

Thank you. Have a great day!

Open Download Windows 10 Disc Image, select edition and language. Then expand "Verify your download".


Can you add a screenshot of the "verify your download" part? I can't find it. Also, does this work for Windows 10 Enterprise versions? (LTSC, etc.)

@Basj - LTSC isn’t purchasable outside volume licensing, the recommended website, is only applicable to consumer versions. Microsoft has a dedicated website for editions only with volume licenses, on that website, they most certainly provide a checksum. You made no mention of that criteria in your question

@Ramhound Yes it depends on customers, some have Pro, some have LTSC, etc. I made the question general for every version.

@Basj—Except there isn't a single answer that will apply to both consumer and enterprise versions, as how you download Enterprise ISO(s) is different from versions sold directly to consumers (Professional, Home, etc.). The "verify your download" will just display a checksum for the file. To be clear, the file is dynamic, so no two attempts to download the ISO will result in the same file and checksum.

@Ramhound why do you mean by the file is dynamic? Example: Windows 10 Enterprise 2021 LTSC is available in this ISO: en-us_windows_10_enterprise_ltsc_2021_x64_dvd_d289cf96.iso, it is not dynamic, it is fixed. Is the SHA256 (or other checksum) of this file available on an official trusted website  (microsoft.com, ...)?

I have dwelled into this(regarding game files, but still the same idea), and only and most secure way,...to be 100% "it's that file!", you have to download "that" file and then run checksum. You wont be able to "just" read SHA online. (excluding premade manifest files, that can do the trick without downloading)
